# Is the "Add Another Answer" button hitbox supposed to be this massive?

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

The button mentioned in the title has a hit-box which spans the complete width of the page (at least in IE and Firefox), i have clicked it quite a few times accidentally; at first i was quite surprised since you get this confirmation popup window without having clicked anywhere near a button.

Vertically the button is also bigger than shown and i think it's a bit irritating...

**Edit:** This applies to the "Answer your Question" button as well.

Comment: It's supposed to be a bit larger than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an error in which element the JavaScript handler was attached to (the containing `<div>` rather than *only* that `<input />`); it will be fixed in the next build.